# Prove $2<x,y> \le |x|^2+|y|^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we are working in an inner product space where $<x,x>=|x|^2$.

I tried using Cauchy but failed

Edit: we are learning about Euclidean norms and under products.

Comment: $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0$

Comment: Start with $0\leq |x-y|^2=<x-y,x-y>$.

Comment: Thanks I get it now

Comment: In case anyone's confused @Loobear23's comment is a good starting-point; one just needs Cauchy-Schwarz to finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Cauchy-Schwarz, use the result from which it's proved: that $|z|\ge0$, with equality iff $z=0$. Can you see which $z$ satisfies $|x|^2+|y|^2-2\langle x,\,y\rangle=|z|^2$?

Answer (score 1):

$\langle x-y,x-y \rangle=$

$ \langle x,x \rangle -2 \langle x,y\rangle +\langle y,y \rangle \ge 0$.

Equaliy for $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

use $|x|^2+|y|^2-2<x,y>=|x-y|^2>0$
like in the case of real numbers